# use awk for printing selected rows

Tags: awk

I have a text file and i want to print only selected rows of it. Below is the dummy format of the text file:

```
Name Sub Marks percentage
A     AB  50     50
Name Sub Marks percentage
b     AB  50     50
Name Sub Marks percentage
c     AB  50     50
Name Sub Marks percentage
d    AB  50     50
```

I need the output as:(Don't need heading before every record and need only 3 columns omitting "MARKS")

```
Name Sub  percentage
A     AB     50
b     AB     50
c     AB     50
d     AB      50
```

Please Suggest me a form of awk command using which I can achieve this, and thanks for supporting.

Comment: Just a small enhancement needed, If the last column say Remarks is added in above table, and its data is in string format like "Student is pass/fail" then how can we format this using awk.

any suggestions on how to modify below:

awk '(NR == 1) || ((NR % 2) == 0) {print $1" "$2" "$4}' inputFile

Answer (score 1):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk 'NR==1 || !(NR%2){ print $1,$2,$4 }' OFS='\t' file
```

- `NR==1 || !(NR%2)` - considering only the 1st and each *even* line
- `OFS='\t'` - output field separator

The output:

```
Name    Sub percentage
A   AB  50
b   AB  50
c   AB  50
d   AB  50
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
awk '(NR == 1) || ((NR % 2) == 0) {print $1" "$2" "$4}' inputFile
```

This will print columns one, two and four but only if the record number is one or even. The results are:

```
Name Sub percentage
A AB 50
b AB 50
c AB 50
d AB 50
```

If you want it nicely formatted, you can use `printf` instead:

```
awk '(NR == 1) || ((NR % 2) == 0) {printf "%-10s %-10s %10s\n", $1, $2, $4}' inputFile

Name       Sub        percentage
A          AB                 50
b          AB                 50
c          AB                 50
d          AB                 50
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have got this done with above solutions

Answer (score 0):

In case that input file has a slight different format above solution will fail. For example:

```
Name Sub Marks percentage
A     AB  50     50
Name Sub Marks percentage
b     AB  50     50
c     AB  50     50
Name Sub Marks percentage
d    AB  50     50
```

In such a case, something like this will work in all cases:

```
$ awk '$0!=h;NR==1{h=$0}' file1
Name Sub Marks percentage
A     AB  50     50
b     AB  50     50
c     AB  50     50
d    AB  50     50
```